# What are the differences between different gaussian functions in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, gaussian

1. [`y = gauss(x,s,m)`](http://mooring.ucsd.edu/software/matlab/doc/toolbox/datafun/gauss.html)
2. [`Y = normpdf(X,mu,sigma)`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/normpdf.html)
3. [`R = normrnd(mu,sigma)`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/normrnd.html)

What are the basic differences between these three functions?

Comment: Just to confuse things more, the Image Processing Toolbox also has `fspecial('gaussian',[1,sz],sigma)` ([documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/fspecial.html)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Y = normpdf(X,mu,sigma)` is the probability density function for a normal distribution with mean `mu` and stdev `sigma`. Use this if you want to know the relative likelihood at a point `X`.

`R = normrnd(mu,sigma)` takes random samples from the same distribution as above. So use this function if you want to simulate something based on the normal distribution.

`y = gauss(x,s,m)` at first glance looks like the exact same function as `normpdf()`. But there is a slight difference: Its calculation is

```
Y = EXP(-(X-M).^2./S.^2)./(sqrt(2*pi).*S)
```

while `normpdf()` uses

```
Y = EXP(-(X-M).^2./(2*S.^2))./(sqrt(2*pi).*S)
```

This means that the integral of `gauss()` from -inf to inf  is `1/sqrt(2)`. Therefore it isn't a legit PDF and I have no clue where one could use something like this.

For completeness we also have to mention `p = normcdf(x,mu,sigma)`. This is the normal cumulative distribution function. It gives the probability that a value is between -inf and `x`.

Answer (score 5):

A few more insights to add to [Leander good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44612441/2627163):

When comparing between functions it is good to look at their source or toolbox. `gauss` is not a function written by Mathworks, so it may be redundant to a function that comes with Matlab.

Also, both `normpdf` and `normrnd` are part of the [Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/index.html) so users without it cannot use them. However, generating random numbers from a normal distribution is quite a common task, so it should be accessible for users that have only the core Matlab. Hence, there *is* a redundant function to `normrnd` which is [`randn`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randn.html) that is part of the core Matlab.